# How to avoid automatic selection of the last option in select tag?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm tring to create a dynamic list of option inside select tag that refresh on click without reload the entire page. This code works, but on click something strange happens.

```
<select id="select_choose" onclick="my_function">
    <option selected>Default value</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT cols1,cols2 FROM my_table";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
        foreach($result as $key => $value) {
            echo "<option>" . $key . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>

<script>
    function my_function() {
      $("#select_choose").load(location.href + " #select_choose>*", "");  
    }
</script>
```

In particular, on click the "default value" is replaced automatically by the last value inserted on MySQL table, that is the last option value created. How can I avoid this behavior? 
On click I want "default value" not to be replaced by the last value. It must stay where it is, and other option listed below.

**UPDATE**

Twisty's solution solved the problem, but there's new issue. When I click on the other options generated, "select" return always "default value". The other options are not selectable.

**2nd UPDATE**

I solved changing "click" with "mouseover".

Comment: `#select_choose>*` - what's this used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's related to using `.load()`. Consider an alternate method. I advise separating the JS and PHP. Make a standalone PHP Script that can do the lookup based on a GET, like an API. Then use JS to query the data via AJAX.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
// Connect to DB
$slt = "SELECT cols1,cols2 FROM my_table";
$stmt = $db->prepare($slt);
$stmt->execute();
$strD = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$results = array();
foreach($strD as $key => $value) {
   array_push($results, $key);
}
// Close DB Connection
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="select_choose">
  <option>Default Value</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loadOptions(url, sObj){
  $("option", sObj).not(":eq(0)").remove();
  $.getJSON(url, function(results){
    $.each(results, function(i, k){
      $("<option>").html(k).appendTo(sObj);
    });
  });
}

$("#select_choose").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  loadOptions("get_options.php", $(this));
  return true;
});

loadOptions("get_options.php", $("#select_choose"));
```

This will load the options and anytime the `select` element is clicked, it will load them again, removing any previous `option` elements except for the first option, the default.

**Update**

You might need to exclude the `<option>` elements from your click event to ensure they do not get replaced.

```
$("#select_choose").not("option").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  loadOptions("get_options.php", $(this));
  return true;
});
```

If you need more help, might need a better example of code / HTML.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it doesn't work, maybe I made a mistake. In `get_options.php` I inserted the php code. HTML and JS are on the "Homepage", where there was my code. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should separate your PHP code in getting the options so that you can call it through ajax to make it dynamically.

Comment: @Rayleigh first test your PHP page, you should be able to navigate to it directly and get a response, it should be in JSON format. Then test with your Homepage and look for any JavaScript errors in your console.

Comment: Edit: @Twisty when I click on other options value, select return always the "default value". Any suggestion?

Comment: @Rayleigh please update your OP and include an update of the code you're now using.

Comment: @Twisty I didn't make any change to your code. The initial problem was due to position of JS code. Placed just before the `</body>` tag works great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203053/discussion-between-rayleigh-and-twisty).